# Correct method call

Tags: java

This is the code that we have been provided with. I've been revising for an exam:

```
public class Car
{
public int numberOfSeats;
private String model;
private int engineCode;
public Car(String model)
{
model = model;
}
public int getSeats()
{
return numberOfSeats;
}
private String getModel()
{
return model;
}
public void setEngineCode(int code)
{
int n = code * 2;
if(code >= 100) {
engineCode = n;
}
else {
engineCode = code;
}
}
}
```

The question is regarding a method call. I believe that it is (b) but am not sure why. Any explanation would be brilliant.

Which of the following is a correct call of the getSeats method. (Assume `car` holds a
`Car` object.)

(a) `String s = car.getSeats();`
(b) `int n = car.getSeats();`
(c) `car getSeats();`

Comment: Are you going to sit the exam?

Comment: If you want extra-points, you may tell the teacher that the class is buggy, because every car will always have a null model.

Comment: Please tell your master to join SO and start posting himself all the questions here, as you are not even trying to think 0.00000001% for the reason for the answer (b)

Answer (score 3):

It's b) indeed. The method call must be assigned to an int since that is the type it returns

Answer (score 2):

It's b. `getSeats()` returns int value.

Answer (score 2):

It is b because the method is not static (so you need an instance of Car -- e.g. car variable -- to call this on) and also because it returns int. Last but not least in Java you need the dot in between the variable/classname and the method.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, (b) is right.

(a) doesn't work, because `getSeats()` returns a value of type `int` and you can't assign that to a variable of type `String`

(c) doesn't work, because it's not legal Java syntax. It looks similar to a method declaration of a method called `getSeats` returning a `car` object.

Answer (score 1):

It is (b).

The method getSeats() is defined to return an `int`

```
public ___int___ getSeats()
{
    return numberOfSeats;
}
```

(underscores used for emphasis)

so you store its returned value in an int.

Answer (score 1):

It's b. The Value your method returns is from the `int`-type.

Answer (score 1):

You call

```
public int getSeats()
{
    return numberOfSeats;
}
```

Which returns an `int` so you should assign it to an int... (b if it's not clear enough)

Answer (score 1):

Its all about ***watch and decide*** strategy. No `brainstorming` session required here.

> When return type of a method is one of the  primitive type, the variable holding
>   the return value must also be defined
>   of the same type.

Since the return type of `getseats( )` is a `int`, **(b) is the correct answer.**

Answer (score 0):

the answer is b because it returns an integer, in a it tries to take an integer into a string which is not cool. the last one is kinda trying to create a `car` object with name `getSeats();` which is not cool too.